# throw 404 error when route is not satisfied

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

using the default route

```
  routes.MapRoute(
      "Admin",                                              // Route name
      "Admin/{action}",                           // URL with parameters
      new { controller = "Admin", action = "Index" }  // Parameter defaults
  );
```

lots of routes (approx. 90%) for our application are working, so that's fine.

Now when the user enters `/logon/strangeroute`, MVC offcourse throws an error because i don't have the `strangeroute` action in my `logoncontroller`.

Using the catch all exception handler in the `global.asax.cs`, i can't find to get the difference between routing errors (i call this a routing error) and another error (thrown in the rest of the code).

I would like to discriminate betweek the types of errors because when the route gives an error it most of the time is a 404 error, and i want to redirect the user to the 404 page and not to the normal, generic, error page.

One soultion would be to create all the routes for all the pages and dismiss the existing default route and implement a catch-all route but i'd prefer not to create a separate route for every url.

Is there another way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test if the [Exception](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.exception.aspx) you caught is an [HttpException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpexception.aspx) and if it is use the [GetHttpCode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpexception.gethttpcode.aspx) method on it to see if it is 404.

Comment: Thanks Darin, that works! one related question before implementing this: what do you think is a better solution: hardcode 100 routes for every page and one catch all route to redirect to the 404 page, or hardcode 1 'generic' route and catch all 'wrong' url's in the error handler? the 'problem' with the latter is that when the app is flooded with bad urls, the app will throw (expensive as i always read) loads of exceptions....

Comment: "Hardcode 100 routes for every page" sounds expensive from a time/maintainability perspective.